# Want to fetch image from iphone Library using Zbar Sdk for QR code

Tags: iphone, qr-code, zbar-sdk

I am using ZbarSdk for QR Codes, but it is fetching image from camera, and i want it to fetch image from library, so that i can test it on simulator, but don't know where to implement code for it. I know how to fetch from library rather than camera,but don't know where and how to implement that code. Can anyone help me out in this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok can you guide me how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible through Zbar sdk, as it doest not allowed.